# Assign Values in Excel

Tags: excel

I have excel 2016. I want to assign ID number that increments only when there is a gap on sequential values from next column as the image below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the rows run from 1 to 10 and columns from A to C:

> C1
>
> `1`

> C2 onwards
>
> `=IF(B2=B1+1, C1, C1+1)`